# Check for any Account is logged in at Google

Tags: php, yii2, google-calendar-api

On my site there is a Google Calendar with Userevents. If noone is logged into Google the container with the Calendar is Empty.

Is there a way to get something like:

```
if($googleConnection = true) {
    //do something
} else {
    echo 'Befor you can use this go to google.de an log in with your Account.'
}
```

**PS:**

Found a soulution:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_login_status(network, status){

    if(status == false){
        alert('NOT LOGGED IN');
    }
    if(status == true){
        alert('Logged In');
    }


}


</script>

<img style="display:none;"
onload="show_login_status('Google', true)"
onerror="show_login_status('Google', false)"
src="https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen%2Fimages%2Flogos%2Faccounts_logo.png&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen%2Fimages%2Flogos%2Faccounts_logo.png&chtml=LoginDoneHtml&checkedDomains=youtube&checkConnection=youtube%3A291%3A1"
/>
```

Comment: Not sure what apis you are using. Those probably already support it. But you could try the following https://robinlinus.github.io/socialmedia-leak/, that is for JS but with php you could try the same trick

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! Thanks for sharing it!